# Difference whilst using ";" or "|" symbols in command lines

Tags: linux, bash

I guess everything is in the title. I am currently learning about bash scripts and I read that we can either use the "|" symbol, or the ";" symbol to execute two commands on one command line.

This question is just by curiosity, does anybody know what difference does it make?

Comment: given `a | b`, the `|` (pipe) takes the output of `a` and feeds it to `b` as input. given `a; b`, you're just executing two programs sequentially. `a` runs, then `b` runs, but there's no chaining of input/output.

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon lets the output of the program echo to the tty.

Pipe hands that output to the program to the right of the pipe.

E.g.

```
# execute foo, then execute bar,
# letting each program output to the terminal
foo ; bar

# execute foo and bar at the same time,
# hooking up the STDOUT from foo into the STDIN to bar,
# letting bar output to the terminal
foo | bar
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I clearly understand the interest of using the pipe. However, is the semi-colon only used for presentation sake?

Comment: @L911 If you have to ask if the difference is only cosmetic, you don't understand the difference. The only advice I can give is try using the command line, then you feel comfortable, try writing your own scripts.

Comment: Thanks to the other answers, some researches and test scripts I know clearly understand how it works!

Answer (score 2):

These two symboles have different usage.

### semicolon symbol

; is used to do some commands after each other without enter.

```
echo 1; echo 2; echo 3
# is equal to:
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
```

### pipe symbol

pipe is a interprocess communication way.
process1 can send something to process2
here, command1 and command2 are process.

```
command1 | command2
```

the output of command1 is given to command2 as an input

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `;` separator is sequential, as in C:

```
ls ; sort
```

In this example, first `ls` is run, and bash will `wait()` for its completion; then `sort` is run.

The `|` separator means two things: the commands around it are run in parallel, and the output of the left command is redirected to the input of the right command through a pipe :

```
ls | sort
```

There are other separators in bash: `&` (parallel), `||` and `&&` (sequential).

Comment: Thank you, I just did not know that | was called a pipe, making my researches a bit difficult. :)